# Type Mismatch Error - charting data

Tags: vba, compiler-errors, type-mismatch

```
Sub Button2_Click()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim xTitle As Range
Dim xData As Range
Dim yColumn As Long
Dim yTitle As Range
Dim yData As Range
Dim GraphRange As Range


'Find last row with data
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Set x-axis title and data
Set xTitle = Range("A1")
Set xData = Range("A2" & LastRow)


 'Find Cap, set y-axis title

= Range("B1")


'set y-axis data
**yData = Range("B2" & LastRow)**

'set total graph range
Set GraphRange = Union(xTitle, xData, yTitle, yData)

'create chart
 ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
 ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatter
 ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=GraphRange
 ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet
 ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementLegendNone)
 ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "MM Index"
 ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis)
 Selection.Caption = xTitle
 ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleRotated)
 Selection.Caption = yTitle

Application.ScreenUpdating = True



End Sub
```

Hi, I am trying to chart a range of data with the X axis coming from col A and Y axis from B. 
I can not stop getting a compile error for type mismatch. Can someone please explain what is causing this error and how to avoid it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

your xData and yData are not set properly. Replace

```
Set xData = Range("A2" & LastRow) 
Set yData = Range("B2" & LastRow)
```

by

```
Set xData = Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
Set yData = Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
```